# Does rewriting files negatively affect SEO?

Tags: seo

I have a static website. I update the pages by uploading the upgraded versions with Filezilla on the server. When I do that the files on the server get rewritten with their new versions. I have noticed that whenever I update my website using this method, the ranking of my website in google gets worse and after a few days of no upgrades it goes back to its previous position. That has happened 3 times. Is my assumption that the reason for this is the fact that I rewrite the server files with new ones correct or does it have nothing to do with SEO and reason may be something else? If that is the case, is there a way around that without having to make my website dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a web page is updated and Google has fetched the new page, Google will index the new page. If the page has changed significantly enough, the metrics will change and the newly updated page will perform differently for a period while it settles into the SERPs (search engine result pages). It will, in time, perform as it should.

Changes to a site, updating pages, adding pages, removing pages, is a disruption and will effect how a site or page performs for a period. This is to be expected. This is how search engines work.

There is nothing for you to do but to work on your site and be patient. There is nothing to worry about. You are fine.

Answer (score 0):

SEO takes time. You should be keeping a record of changes if you are intentionally changing your pages to boost SEO. It takes time for bots/google to evaluate your sites SEO value. it’s never immediate. Immediate changes are from outside of what googles decision on your ranking is. It could even be your own activity working on the site, checking pages talking to people about the new page, they visit. Then you move on to your next project. Dips in traffic are just that. If you update your page and traffic suddenly dips it could be because how people ended up on your page is no longer agreeing with how google has rated you. So they send in new bots, ect to re-evaluate your page. You can even request for google to crawl your page if this is the case. Try comparing the bot activity with your traffic and changes. You need to look a little further for the best information to use within your SEO decision making. First of all, how are they arriving on your page. Look at the terms they are searching for which leads them to your site. Compare that with what is trending within search terms most relevant to the content that a user would find useful. Utilize this information in your meta, keywords, ect. Also compare each seo campaign change with an seo evaluator so you can see trends. Sometimes it’s even as weird as getting penalized for the html/content ratio, keyword stuffing or irrelevant useful information in the eyes of your keywords.